# Struggling to install pyephem with pip3 on a Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pip, pyephem

I can't seem to get pyephem Python framework installed using pip3 on my EC2 instance. This is the message I get:

https://pastebin.com/erL7VhYV

I tried to install various dependencies I could find by running

```
yum search astro
```

But it didn't help. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `Python.h` — the main include file from Python sources. Install `python3-dev` package or how it's called in RPM distributions (I'm from DEB world).

Comment: So it was that simple! Thanks!